# Вывод данных на другом сайте

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http

У меня есть к примеру форма на сайте. Пользователь там вводит свои данные. Но мне нужно, чтобы эти данные еще водились параллельно на другом сайте в тех же формах. 
Почитал про CORS, но как понимаю, от туда идет только вывод данных с др.сайта.
Подскажите, возможно ли вообще такое реализовать? К примеру через ajax-запрос или при помощи http-запроса . 
 Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Правильно ли понимаю, что вы хотите что бы при сабмите формы введённые данные отобразились в интерфейсе другого сайта?

Comment: Да. При отправке данных ввелись там же также само. К примеру пользователь регистрируется на моем сайте, и парралельно с этим еще на другом. Чтобы можно было реализовать. Ибо через api того сайта, такое не реализуется

Comment: А у вас есть доступ и к первому и ко второму сайтам? Я имею в виду доступ к исходному коду. Иначе как установив обмен сообщениями я другого способа не вижу. Напрямую отправить запрос на второй сайт, догадываюсь, не позволяет XSS защита?

Comment: Нет доступа. Конкретно, уже скажу - мне нужно с регистрицией на сайте - регистрировать почту еще в gmail. Но google api это позволяет только с платными аккаунтами (типа бизнес акков) сделать. Вот и ищу все возможные способы

Comment: Вы можете пойти по принципу автоматизированного тестирования - написать сценарий(для сервера) который будет открывать страницу и заполнять форму. Но надёжность этого метода стремится к 0 и запнётся об первую же капчу.
Сделать имитацию запроса тоже не получится. Не думаю что в Гугл он будет таким простым.

Comment: Спасибо, звучит конечно красиво. Копать стоит в тему "Автоматизириваное тестирование"? Правильно понимаю? То ранее с этими не сталкивался. И на счет капчи, планировал выводить ее у себя на сайте, и чтобы пользователи от нее избавлялись

Comment: Да, "Автоматизириваное тестирование" Но, повторюсь - это всё равно что забивать гвозди скрипкой.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="другой сайт" target="frame_name">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Вы явно мой вопрос не поняли

Comment: @nikitaAbramov Напротив, я понял Ваш вопрос и дал на него хороший, правильный ответ. Доверьтесь мне.